# What is the use case of program's secret key after initial deployment?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, deploy

Is there any other use case of the program's secret key once the program is deployed? If I am correct, subsequent updates don't require the program's secret key. Can anyone do anything to the program if the program's secret key gets leaked ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The secret key of the program address is only needed for the initial deploy. Once it's deployed (to all networks) there is no need for it. As of now, at least.